# Detect in Javascript when HTML5 <video> loop restarts?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a looping HTML5 video using `<video loop="true">`, and I want to know when the video loops. The event listener `play` only fires when the video is started initially, and `ended` never fires.

The imprecise nature of `timeupdate` makes me nervous using `if ( v.currentTime <= 0 )`, but it does seem to work. Is there a better way to detect when the video restarts?

Here's my basic setup:

```
<video autoplay="true" loop="true" muted="true">
<source src="vidoe.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
<div id="Video-Time"></div>

<script>
var v = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]
var t = document.getElementById('Video-Time');

v.addEventListener('timeupdate',function(event){
  t.innerHTML = v.currentTime;
  if ( v.currentTime <= 0 ) { console.log("Beginning!"); } // It does trigger when looping, surprisingly
},false);
v.addEventListener('play', function () {
  console.log("play!"); // Only triggered when the video initially starts playing, not when the loop restarts
},false);
v.addEventListener('ended', function () {
  console.log("ended!"); // Never triggered
},false);
</script>
```

Comment: The `seeked` event should fire when the video starts over, but if you have controls on the video it will fire when the video is seeked by the user as well.

Comment: to reduce the impact of the user scrubbing I'd maybe set a flag when currentTime reaches the last second of the video, and then if there is a successful seek to currentTime of 0  assume that the loop has triggered

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think the most reliable way is to loop it yourself. Remove the `loop` attribute and do this:

```js
document.querySelector('video').addEventListener('ended', function () {
  console.count('loop restart');
  this.play();
})
```

```html
<video autoplay muted src="https://rawgit.com/bower-media-samples/big-buck-bunny-480p-5s/master/video.mp4"></video>
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution than the more common check the currentTime and fire event solution. TIMTOWDI and very nice out of the box thinking!

Comment: not working for me

Comment: @June it’s you then. This is 2 lines of code that 23+ other people have been using since 2015

Comment: @June maybe remove the `loop` attribute

Comment: If you are using src from blob it will need to re-fetch the whole video from memory. Depending on the video size can take a significant amount of time every time you invoke play. If you are using the `loop` attribute the video player does not have a delay between loops. Always measure that this is not the case for you.

Answer (score 10):

I just had to do this for mobile. You can't do the accepted answer on mobile because mobile requires user interaction to run play() again (in many cases and especially in most web views)

The only thing we can rely on in "timeupdate" for this is `currentTime==0`. Since we know `currentTime==0` is going to run in the "timeupdate" 2-7 times depending hardware/whatever, we can set a boolean to capture just the first time it runs by setting the boolean to false immediately after the condition is met, then on timer we can reset the bool.

Best solution I can conceive. We should just have a "looped" event listener.

```js
let loopCount = 0;
let throttle = true;
document.querySelector('video').addEventListener("timeupdate", () => {
    const video = document.querySelector('video');
    if (video.currentTime === 0 && throttle) {
        throttle = false,
        loopCount += 1;
        console.log(loopCount);
        setTimeout(()=> { 
            throttle = true;
        }, 500);
    }
}, true);
```

```html
<video autoplay muted loop src="https://rawgit.com/bower-media-samples/big-buck-bunny-480p-5s/master/video.mp4"></video>
```

Comment: The smallest `video.currentTime` I'm seeing on my Windows machine with Chrome is 0.000163. So not exactly `=== 0`...

Comment: That was a good idea, but it is not reliable since the `timeupdate` event does not fire consistently, but depending on the system load ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event)).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how robust this method is but something I've found through

```
player.on("timeupdate", function(e) {
    console.log(player.currentTime)
});
```

is that if a user scrubs to 0 time, the `timeupdate` event fires twice with `currentTime==0` and if the video loops it fires `timeupdate` 3 times with `currentTime==0`. This seems to hold across FF, Chrome, IE but I wonder if it's related to common implementation of spec or is hardware dependent. i.e. speedy machine 3 ticks, slow machine 5 ticks of `currentTime==0`

There is also player.played which will return a TimeRanges object of ranges played. So:

```
player.on("timeupdate", function(e) {
    var tr = player.played;
    var hasLoopedOnce = (tr.end(tr.length-1)==player.duration);
    console.log(hasLoopedOnce);
});
```

The problem with this is that the ranges wont reset after each iteration so it's only good for detecting the first loop. I've tried player.played=null but to no avail.

But using these methods to set flags and combining with `player.currentTime <=0`  may be enough for some scenarios if indeed just `player.currentTime <=0` is not enough.