# Javascript - If video is looped do something

Tags: javascript, html, video

How do I check if a video in HTML is looped via javascript. If the video is looped do something and else do something else. Will the following code work?

```
var vid = document.getElementById('video');

if(vid.looped) {
    //code...
}else{
    //code...
}
```

If this isn't the correct code. What is the correct code?

Comment: Use the `onended` event to set a flag, then maybe try the `play` event and say - if the ended flag is `true` and the `play` event is fired then the user has replayed/looped the video. There may be small issues e.g. I don't know whether the `play` event is fired on videos with the `loop` attribute. In that case you could use the `timeupdate` event and just watch for the `currentTime` going from near the end to the beginning.

Comment: Ok I am trying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect in Javascript when HTML5 <video> loop restarts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271706/detect-in-javascript-when-html5-video-loop-restarts)