# How can I perfectly synchronize a CSS animation to the start of a looping HTML video?

Tags: javascript, html, css, synchronization, css-animations

On my the landing page of my site I have a fullscreen showreel video showcasing my work. I'd like my logo to fade in and overlay a 3s black screen at the start of the video before fading out over the first clip.

Instead of embedding the logo in the video, I'd like to overlay it as an SVG as the quality is much higher. The video is 54s long and I need to reduce the video quality to improve the page load time.

I have managed to partially achieve this with a CSS animation and Javascript. The 54s video autoplays when the page loads, and the 54s CSS logo animation starts:

**HTML**

```
<section class="hero">
    <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop" id="myShowreel">
            <source src="video/myshowreel.mp4" data-src="video/myshowreel.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="d-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
            <div class="p-2 bd-highlight"><img src="img/branding/my-logo.svg" class="logo" id="myLogo" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS Logo Animation**

```
.elementToFadeInAndOut {
    -webkit-animation: fadeinout 54s linear infinite;
    animation: fadeinout 54s linear infinite;
    opacity: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    1% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    2.5% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    5.55555555556% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    8% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    1% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    2.5% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    5.55555555556% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    8% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly for the first couple of video loops, but from there it becomes more noticeably out of sync. The logo starts to appear at the end of the showreel instead of at the start.

I suspect this is because the HTML video's loop attribute isn't perfect/seamless and there is a small delay before the video restarts. I have checked that my showreel is exactly 54 seconds long in Premiere Pro before exporting.

I haven't learned Javascript yet, but to try and circumvent this problem I searched for a Javascript solution to 'detect' when the video restarts and play the CSS animation. That way, the animation would always play at the start of the video rather than rely on timings.

**Javascript**

```
    <script>
        let video = document.getElementById("myShowreel");
        let timeToAnimate = 0;
        let i = window.setInterval(() => {
        if (video.currentTime >= timeToAnimate) {
            document.getElementById("myLogo").classList.add('elementToFadeInAndOut');
        }
        },100);
    </script>
```

However, the problem persists and the logo animation still becomes out of sync after a few video loops. I'm not sure if this Javascript is working.

I would really appreciate some pointers in the right direction to solve this syncing issue, or learn if there's a better way to do this. Would it be better to use Javascript to loop the video, rather than use the HTML attribute?

Comment: JavaScript doesn’t give you a cast iron real time system. Other things will be happening in your system. You cannot rely on things like setInterval to be exact. Can you edit the video to get rid of that black bit at the start?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect when the video start new loop by adding a `seeked` listener to the video. I tried to listen to `ended` but it didn't trigger when the loop start.

But when user try to drag the timeline it will trigger. To prevent this you need to disable controls on your video.

```
let video = document.getElementById("myShowreel");

video.addEventListener('seeked', (event) => {
   document.getElementById("myLogo").classList.add('elementToFadeInAndOut');
});
```

Or you can remove loop, and trigger play when video ended.

```
let video = document.getElementById("myShowreel");
let logo = document.getElementById("myLogo");

video.addEventListener('play', (event) => {
   logo.classList.add('elementToFadeInAndOut');
});

video.addEventListener('ended', (event) => {
   logo.classList.remove('elementToFadeInAndOut');
   video.play();
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/seeked_event

and also this might be helpful to you
[Detect in Javascript when HTML5 <video> loop restarts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271706/detect-in-javascript-when-html5-video-loop-restarts)